# Secondary onClick event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 click events on the page by default (blue X, blue +, grey X). Each one opens a modal box.

[image]

Each of those modal boxes, has a button. Two of the modal boxes, the one for the blue X, and the one for the blue +, both have functioning buttons inside. The console message shows for both of these additional click events when I click their respective buttons. I click the button in the modal for the blue X or blue +, and I get the console log message. Good. But this doesn't work fo the grey X.

The other 3rd modal box does open, but the button inside doesn't work. This button has an id=

```
remPostConfirm
```

The code for this button that doesn't' work is:

```
showRemPost = function(id, url, lname) {
    console.log("remPost1");
    if (isAuth) {
        $('#remPostConfirm').off('click').on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("remPost2");
        });
        $('#remPostModal .description').html('<p>Post: ' + url + '</p><p>From List: ' + lname + '</p><div  id="remListConfirm" class="mini ui button">Remove</div >');
        $('#remPostModal').modal('show');
    } else {
        deniedAccess();
    }
}
```

The other two buttons that do work, have essentially the same code.

I am lost as to why this no longer works, as this 3rd modal button used to work. If you try to click on the grey X for this modal to load, then on the "Remove" button, you won't get a console log message like the other two give (the blue X and blue +).

Here is a jsfiddle example for you test and see.

https://jsfiddle.net/qrmrfrhj/16/

Sorry for the JS being included in the HTML, I can't get the example to work if I separate it down below. If you want to help me get that working before downvoting me, that would be nice. Thanks.

Thank you for any help. Peace.

Comment: Downvoted until you tidy that mess inside jsfiddle link.

Comment: Better? I can't get it to work if I put the script int he bottom, sorry.

Comment: Your code on js is very unclear together with your question. Agree with @K.Daniek.
I tried all the "x" anyway and they all work oO

Comment: I have redone the post. Please let me know if it is clear now, or not. Thank you.

Comment: Here's your fiddle with everything in the proper place: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qrmrfrhj/14/

Comment: Use the Extenal Resources section to link to external CSS and JS files, use the Javascript popup dialog to select the jQuery framework.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was sticking the CSS link onthe right side panel, and the JS I had the script tags included. https://jsfiddle.net/qrmrfrhj/16/ is now corrected.

Comment: Can I remake this questions after deleting it? With a flag, it's going to be treated like garbage and I won't get any help for it. Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo. In `showRemPost` you have `id="remListConfirm"`, it should be `id="remPostConfirm"`

Comment: But you're binding the `.click()` handler before you add the HTML. You need to put the call to `.on("click")` after `.html()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I stupidly forgot that I added the link creation there and didn't notice it was being created after the binding of the event which wouldn't work... Sorry to bother you and thank you very much for this!  Can you make that your answer, I will upvote it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in `showRemPost`.

First, in the HTML that you add to `#remPostModal`, you have `id="remListConfirm"`, but you're adding a click handler on `#remPostConfirm`. `remListConfirm` is already used in `remListModal`, you shouldn't duplicate it here.

Second, you bind the click handler before you create the button with `.html()`. So when you create the button, it doesn't have a click handler. You need to change the order. There's no need for `.off()`, since a brand new element won't have a click handler. Alternatively you could use event delegation. Or you could do it like the other dialogs, where you don't overwrite the button that's in the original HTML.

```
  showRemPost = function(id, url, lname) {
    console.log("remPost1");
    if (isAuth) {
      $('#remPostModal .description').html('<p>Post: ' + url + '</p><p>From List: ' + lname + '</p><div  id="remPostConfirm" class="mini ui button">Remove</div >');
      $('#remPostConfirm').on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("remPost2");
      });

      $('#remPostModal').modal('show');
    } else {
      deniedAccess();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. The id of the "remove" button in your popup is actually `remListConfirm`, not `remPostConfirm`
2. You're creating your events BEFORE you add the button to the DOM. That means when JS looks for an element with the id 'remListConfirm', it's going to find nothing and thus not attach the event to anything.

The solution is to change the id in your JS to `remListConfirm` and move the .html line ABOVE the lines where you create the click events. Here's the section fixed:

```
                 if (isAuth) {
                        $('#remPostModal .description').html('<p>Post: ' + url + '</p><p>From List: ' + lname + '</p><div  id="remListConfirm" class="mini ui button">Remove</div >');
                    $('#remListConfirm').off('click').on("click", function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("remPost2");
                    });

                    $('#remPostModal').modal('show');
                } else {
                    deniedAccess();
                }
            }
```